# Direct3D keeping different textures for a lot of objects

Tags: textures, direct3d

I'm exploring the world of procedural generation with the help of directX. A problem I'm hitting is with textures. I'm generating a lot of objects and each one stores a unique texture in memory.

I'm currently using 512x512 textures, but if I go more detailed memory starts spiking exponentially.

What is a good way to handle such case? Generating textures each frame sounds quite like a refresh rate freezing approach.